# Como remover o "data" que definimos no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

No jQuery, é possível definir valores para um atributo através do `data`.

Assim:

```
$('body').data({id: 1, nome: 'stack'});
```

E o resultado disso seria:

```
console.log($('body').data()); // {id: 1, nome: 'stack'}
```

Porém se eu quiser reescrever o objeto, não consigo fazer isso com `data`.

```
$('body').data({nome: 'stack'});

console.log($('body').data()); // {id:1, nome: 'stack'}
```

Note que o `id` continuou ali, mesmo eu redefinindo o valor do data.

Como é que posso apagar um valor do `data` ou todo o valor do `data` no jQuery?

Comment: você pode anular o id: `$('body').data.id = null;`

Comment: Como pode remover: `delete $('body').data.id;`

Comment: Como também pode remover usando a função `removeData()` do jQuery: `$('body').data.removeData('id');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jQuery.removeData() permite remover valores que foram previamente inseridos usando o jQuery.data().

Vamos a um exemplo:

```js
var div = $( "div" )[ 0 ];
$( "span:eq(0)" ).text( "" + $( "div" ).data( "test1" ) );
jQuery.data( div, "test1", "VALUE-1" );
jQuery.data( div, "test2", "VALUE-2" );
$( "span:eq(1)" ).text( "" + jQuery.data( div, "test1" ) );
jQuery.removeData( div, "test1" );
$( "span:eq(2)" ).text( "" + jQuery.data( div, "test1" ) );
$( "span:eq(3)" ).text( "" + jQuery.data( div, "test2" ) );
```

```css
div {
    margin: 2px;
    color: blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
<div>value1 before creation: <span></span></div>
<div>value1 after creation: <span></span></div>
<div>value1 after removal: <span></span></div>
<div>value2 after removal: <span></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Também tem como fazer diretamente: `$('body').removeData('id')`

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito dessa forma, boa!

Answer (score 3):

O `$.data`, quando chamado com um único argumento do tipo objeto, não atribui um único valor - atribui vários. Existe uma correspondência entre os atributos individuais setados pelo jQuery e os atributos `data-*` no HTML:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify($("#teste").data());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste" data-foo="10" data-bar="20" data-baz="30"></div>
```

O `data` sem parâmetros é um "atalho" para se acessar todos os atributos de uma vez. O com um parâmetro do tipo objeto, um atalho para atribuir vários. Mas para acessar cada um individualmente, é necessário usar o método com um primeiro argumento string (o nome do atributo desejado):

```js
var el = $("#teste");
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(el.data()) + "<br>";
el.data("foo", 40);
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(el.data()) + "<br>";
el.removeData("bar");
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(el.data()) + "<br>";

document.body.innerHTML += el.data("baz");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste" data-foo="10" data-bar="20" data-baz="30"></div>
```